# Email verification can not stop spam account?

Tags: asp.net, spam-prevention

I built a web site with `ASP.NET MVC` and use email verification on account registration. But I found email verification cannot stop spam accounts.

There are still lots of registered and confirmed account that are spam accounts.

Can these spam programs automatically go to confirm account with the link from email?

Comment: What logic are you implementing for confirming user email? are you sending any unique key on mail for confirming user email id?

Comment: @Sumit Chourasia: yes, there is a link in email including a token string. I wonder if it will be better that I change it from "Get" to "Post"? From the link in email, user can land to a page with a button, after click the button, post to server to verify.

Comment: generate a random string, send the key to user's email id at the same time store it in your database too. next time when user confirm the key, just match the code present in your database, if it matches, account is activated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this example -

This is very basic tutorial explained how to create database and proper activation code.

http://www.9lessons.info/2013/11/php-email-verification-script.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Email validation stops spam account. Nowadays most of the website using this to prevent spam account. As you are facing issue to stop spam with this then you can choose other methods also to block spam.

These are some of the best and simple tricks to stop spam account on your website:-

1. Administration approval for new users:- This is the best method to prevent spam. Approval of users in your hand, if there is any fault then you can block them manually.
2. CAPTCHA:- Another way to stop spam user registration.
3. reCAPTCHA:- In reCAPTCHA, users need to click a checkbox, instead of solving math problems or questions answer.
4. IP Address blocking:- As you know each computer has a unique id, which is IP address. When you find that IP Address is sending spam to your site, you can block them.

You can choose any one option to prevent spam and for better security of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that can be done pretty easily.  Why don't you use captcha, google seems to provide a free service. http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha